# error bootmessages. PAM unable to load. PAM adding faulty module

Tags: boot, pam, acpi, lightdm, journalctl

So when booting my Mint 20.1 I always see a short error. With `journalctl -b`I can see the following suspecious logs

```
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel: ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 000000002b263334 (20190816/exresop-66)
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel: ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20190816/dswexec-431)
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PDC]
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_PDC]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel:   Arg0:   000000002ba16ef6 <Obj>           Buffer(12) 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
Feb 16 15:28:43 username-home kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

and

```
Feb 16 16:28:43 username-home kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid
```

and twice with one second delay

```
Feb 16 15:28:45 username-home lightdm[952]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb 16 15:28:45 username-home lightdm[952]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Feb 16 15:28:45 username-home lightdm[952]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb 16 15:28:45 username-home lightdm[952]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
```

but at least the last error does not seem to be really a problem [according to this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1404172)?

any soothening or human warning about those errors welcome

Answer (score 1):

The first two problems are most likely just [firmware bugs](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198781) so to fix them you could try to update your firmware or you may want to contact the vendor of the firmware, so that they can fix the bug (e.g see [DebuggingACPI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI) for more information), but I don't think these messages are something serious to worry about and you can probably simply ignore them.

Regarding the last problem, you probably just don't have these (optional) modules (e.g.libpam-kwallet5) installed. You can tell PAM (by editing `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`) that some libraries are only optionally installed on your system and them possible missing is expected.

C.f. [man pam.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/pam.conf.5.html):

> If the type value from the list above is prepended with a - character the PAM library will not log to the system log if it is not possible to load the module because it is missing in the system. This can be useful especially for modules which are not always installed on the system and are not required for correct authentication and authorization of the login session.

While you can change the PAM configuration on your system in my opinion this should probably be fixed by your distribution (the maintainers of the lightdm package).